# Having trouble deleting PFFile in Parse using opensource parse-server

Tags: ios, rest, parse-platform

I have a collection that has references to images, and when the user updates that collection with new images, I want to delete the old images.  I am keeping references to the URL for the old images to pass into a function that is written in the cloud code.

I am running all of this local on my computer, however I get the same issue when I run this with the server running on Heroku.  This is being called from the iOS SDK.

Here is the function in question:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('removeOldFilesFromDB', function (request, response) {

    var fileUrls = request.params.fileUrls;
    var promises = [];

    for (var a = 0; a < fileUrls.length; a++) {

        promises.push(Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: fileUrls[a],
            headers: {
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
                'X-Parse-Master-Key': process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'myMasterKey'
            }
        }));

    }

    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then( function (result) {
        console.log("Successfully deleted files");
        response.success(result);
    }, function(a,b,c,d,e) {
        console.log("Nope jacked it up!");
        response.error("Error deleting files");
    });

})
```

When I call the code in question, I don't even see the DELETE request in the parse-server logs at all.

I have the `verbose: true` flag set in my config, and this is the verbose output to the logs that I get when making this call from the client:

```
verbose: POST /parse/functions/removeOldFilesFromDB { host: 'e0ae0682.ngrok.io',
'x-parse-client-version': 'i1.12.0',
accept: '*/*',
'x-parse-session-token': 'r:5290c76c47678213770765d990ee38b6',
'x-parse-application-id': 'myAppId',
'x-parse-client-key': 'myClientKey',
'x-parse-installation-id': '3fafc219-1c63-4d68-b42f-5caa3e1c27cb',
'accept-language': 'en-us',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'x-parse-os-version': '8.1 (12B411)',
'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
'content-length': '204',
'user-agent': 'Spin%20the%20Bottle/1 CFNetwork/711.1.12 Darwin/14.0.0',
'x-parse-app-build-version': '1',
'x-parse-app-display-version': '1.0',
'x-forwarded-for': '71.163.238.223' } {
"fileUrls": [
    "http://e0ae0682.ngrok.io/parse/files/myAppId/7b5b50e2871af27971be0425f367ab96_file.bin",
    "http://e0ae0682.ngrok.io/parse/files/myAppId/cff909602b60b15331b1ac60a4f08697_file.bin"
  ]
}

Nope jacked it up!
verbose: error: code=141, message=Error deleting files
```

So it's odd that the DELETE call is not even showing up in there. Am I calling it wrong with the Parse.Cloud.httpRequest method or something?

If I hit the values for fileUrl in my browser, it downloads the images I'm trying to delete so the path is correct.

This is on the latest released version of parse-server, 2.2.10.

These were the instructions that I was following thinking that this is the correct way to do this:

https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#files-deleting-files

And this here to make the rest call from the cloud code:

https://parse.com/questions/making-a-rest-call-from-within-cloud-code

According to that, it says I can use Parse.Cloud.httpRequest to make REST calls, so I am not sure what you are referring to as that not the correct ways. Both of those have links to the docs and that is what I followed.

So I am obviously doing something wrong but I am not sure, anyone able to help out?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove myAppId from file URL.

(e.g.)

from

http://e0ae0682.ngrok.io/parse/files<s>/myAppId</s>/7b5b50e2871af27971be0425f367ab96_file.bin

to

http://e0ae0682.ngrok.io/parse/files/7b5b50e2871af27971be0425f367ab96_file.bin

Comment: We actually ended up removing parse completely from the backend, much better solution in the end :)

Comment: Which solution did you choose instead of Parse?

Comment: We ended up not using any out of the box solution and instead are just using our own node.js server.  There is a lot less overhead now that Parse is gone and it's also more secure since we are in 100% control of everything.